# Getting 403 on apache with php on fedora 17

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fedora, http-status-code-403, symlink

I put the projects on `~/public_html/project` and create a soft-link in `/var/www/html/project` which point to `~/public_html/project`.

my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` is shown below

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

PidFile run/httpd.pid

Timeout 60

KeepAlive Off

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

Listen 80

Include conf.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

UseCanonicalName Off

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# Allow SVN access from public
<Directory "/var/www/svn">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir disabled
    # UserDir public_html
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
#   MIMEMagicFile /usr/share/magic.mime
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

HostnameLookups Off

<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/project
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
```

in browser

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /project on this server.
```

I get this error.

`ls -l` result:
`drwxrwxrwx   3 js js 4.0K Nov  1 14:43 public_html/`
for project
`drwxr-xr-x. 6 js js 4.0K Nov  1 16:38 public_html/project/`

I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: What is the owner and group of `~/public_html/project`?

Comment: both are `js` _(current user)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem which is regarding to my home directory.

basically i just solved by using this command

```
$ chmod o+rx ~
```

The answer by +Michael Hampton may help in some way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable httpd to read home directories by SELinux.

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

Comment: SELinux is disabled. so the command you given to me doesn't work. it comes out  
`setsebool:  SELinux is disabled.`

Comment: after these command, it still not working