# Error 403 on Apache, Fedora 22

Tags: apache-2.4, fedora, http-status-code-403

I have installed Apache: `Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Fedora)` and I got a website with Codeigniter. I added a folder `images/` in the root of the  site and I couldn't load the images. When I tries the complete path for the URL of the image I got `403 - You don't have permission to access /images/image.jpg on this server.`

Anyway, that happened just with the images. Any other url from the website worked like a charm. But then I found this answer: [Getting 403 on apache with php on fedora 17](https://serverfault.com/questions/444629/getting-403-on-apache-with-php-on-fedora-17) and using `root` I did:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

And now I get `403 error` for all the urls of the website build in Codeigniter. If I go directly to `http://localhost/` it will show me the `Fedora test page` that you get when you just installed Apache and everything.

Then I read this: http://linux.die.net/man/8/setsebool and tried to reverse whatever I have done by doing:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 0
setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 0
```

But nothing happened. I keep seeing the `Fedora test page` that says that Apache is installed but not configured. Sigh. My ancestors laughing from their graves. Any ideas how to solve this?

PS. The last line of `/var/log/httpd/error_log` is the following:

```
[Fri Jul 31 11:03:38.129795 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 1316] [client 127.0.0.1:51429] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/
```

PS. Now, after all this, I assumed that the reason why I couldn't load the images from that folder was because of the `.htaccess` that Codeigniter has, right? Anyway, after I get this solve probably I'll ask that in another question.

Comment: Where are the _relevant_ error log entries?

Comment: Maybe I can learn something from you today @MichaelHampton I know the `error log file` and `access log file`. Which one are you referring? Or is it another one?